# Web3 retrieving latest transactions

Tags: transactions, web3js, blockchain, blocks, microsoft-azure

Is there any way in the [Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#) Javascript API to retrieve the latest, let's say five, transactions that were done on the blockchain?

The only option I can think of, is by using `web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber, true)` in a for loop and subtracting the blockNumber till you find an object in the `transactions`property.

However, this can take a very long time, because in our case, we have our blockchain on an Azure server and a lot of empty blocks are created by nodes.

EDIT: Not a duplicate of [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/how-can-i-get-the-data-of-the-latest-10-blocks-via-web3-js). I want to know how to find the latest **transactions** in an *efficient* way, without using a for loop that takes *ages* to complete.

Comment: I want to know how to find the latest **transactions** in an _efficient_ way, without using a for loop that takes ages to complete.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to use [BatchRequest](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63711/24916) to reduce the amount of network requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I found this [example](https://gist.github.com/ross-p/bd5d4258ac23319f363dc75c2b722dd9) on Github, someone found a way to scan blocks for transactions asynchronously! If you have a decent CPU, you can hit 300 blocks/second. It is very well documented as well.